# failed to fetch filename from database using jsp

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

I am trying to fetch data from MySQL database to edit.jsp (input form). I am successful to fetch all textfields and dropdowns inedit.jsp. Also I am trying to fetch respective filename(already stored), but filename is not showing on input form i.e. edit.jsp. I tried this but not worked for me.

```html
value='<%=res.getString("filename")%>'
```

Below is the code from edit.jsp to show already stored filename

```html
<tr>
  <td>Select File</td>
  <td>
    <input type="file" name="fileName" multiple="multiple" value='<%=res.getString("filename")%>' />
  </td>
</tr>
```

This is my edit.jsp page

```html
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Timestamp"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Properties" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Document Management System</title>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      
        <style>
            h2 {
                text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px red;
            }
            #Registercontainer {
                max-width: 600px;
                min-width: 320px;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 70px auto;
                border: 2px solid blue;
                border-style: inset;
                border-radius: 8px;
                background-color: aliceblue;
                top: 0;
                padding: 15px;
            }
            #back_form {
                justify-content: center;
            }
            
            .right {
                text-align: right;
                float: right;
            }
            #wgtmsr{
            width:153px;   
           }
           
           .hidden{
               display: none;
           }
            
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            
            function showHide() {
                var checkbox = document.getElementById("chk");
                var hiddeninputs = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");

                for (var i = 0; i != hiddeninputs.length; i++) {
                  if (checkbox.checked) {
                    hiddeninputs[i].style.display = "block";
                  } else {
                    hiddeninputs[i].style.display = "none";
                  }
                }
              }
            
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
         
             <br>
       
    <div id="Registercontainer">
    <div class="RegForm">    
    <div id="back_glob">    
    <div id="back_form">
        
        <%
            String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dmsqms";
            Statement stat = null;
            ResultSet res = null;
            Connection conn = null;
            PreparedStatement stmt = null;
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host,"root","");
            
            
            %>
        <form action="UploadServletClass" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            
            <%
            
            stat = conn.createStatement();
            String zid = request.getParameter("zid");
            
            String data = "select * from dmsfiles where zid = '"+zid+"'";
            
            res = stat.executeQuery(data);
            while(res.next()){
            
            %>
            
            <center><h2>Upload a New Document</h2></center>
            
            <table width="400px" align="center" border="2">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" colspan="2">Form Details</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Z id</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="zid" value='<%=res.getString(1)%>'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" required="" name="firstname" value='<%=res.getString(2)%>'/>
                        
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" required="" name="lastname" value='<%=res.getString(3)%>'/>
                        
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Mail id</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="email" required="" name="mailid" value='<%=res.getString(4)%>'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Division</td>
                    <td>
                    <select name="division" id="wgtmsr" >
                        
                    <option value="<%=res.getString(5)%>"><%=res.getString(5)%></option>
                    
                    <option value="B">B</option>
                    <option value="Z">Z</option>
                    <option value="I">I</option>
                    <option value="CF">CF</option>
                    <option value="P">P</option>
                    <option value="P">TT</option>
                    <option value="P">TC</option>
                    <option value="P">MA</option>
                    <option value="P">Z HYD</option>
                    <option value="P">CC</option>
                    <option value="P">CY</option>
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
               <tr>
                    <td>Department</td>
                    <td>
                    <select name="department" id="wgtmsr">
                    <option value="<%=res.getString(6)%>"><%=res.getString(6)%></option>
                    <option value="IT">IT</option>
                    <option value="Finance">Finance</option>
                    <option value="Logistics">Logistics</option>
                    <option value="Design">Design</option>
                    <option value="Purchase">Purchase</option>
                    <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
                    <option value="Material Management">Material Management</option>
                    
                    </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td>Department Code</td>
                    <td>
                    <select name="costcentercode" id="wgtmsr">
                    <option value="<%=res.getString(7)%>"><%=res.getString(7)%></option>
                    <option value="100115">100115</option>
                    <option value="100138">100138</option>
                    <option value="100630">100630</option>
                    <option value="100812">100812</option>
                    <option value="100823">100823</option>
                    <option value="500904">500904</option>
                    <option value="500907">500907</option>
                    <option value="700415">700415</option>
                    
                    
                    </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Document Number</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" required="" name="documentnumber" value='<%=res.getString(8)%>'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td>Document Name</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" required="" name="documentname" value='<%=res.getString(9)%>'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td>Document Type</td>
                    <td>
                    <select name="Document_Type" id="wgtmsr">
                    <option value="<%=res.getString(10)%>"><%=res.getString(10)%></option>
                    <option value="Agreement">Agreement</option>
                    <option value="Contract">Contract</option>
                    <option value="PO">PO</option>
                    <option value="Invoice">Invoice</option>
                    <option value="COA">COA</option>
                    <option value="Lease Deed">Lease Deed</option>
                    <option value="AMC">AMC</option>
                    <option value="Direct Material">Direct Material</option>
                    <option value="Indirect Material/Services">Indirect Material/Services</option>
                    
                    </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <br><br>
                <tr>
                    <td>Document Category</td>
                    <td>
                    <select name="Document_Category" id="wgtmsr">
                    <option value="<%=res.getString(11)%>"><%=res.getString(11)%></option>    
                    <option value="Customer">Customer</option>
                    <option value="Vendor">Vendor</option>
                    <option value="Internal">Internal</option>
                    
                    </select>
                    </td>
                
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Document Classification</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Document_Classification" id="wgtmsr">
                        <option value="<%=res.getString(12)%>"><%=res.getString(12)%></option>
                        <option value="Public">Public</option>
                        <option value="Internal">Internal</option>
                        <option value="ZF Confidential">ZF Confidential</option>
                        <option value="ZF Strictly Confidential">ZF Strictly Confidential</option>
                    </select>
                    </td>
                
                </tr>
                <br><br>
                
                <tr>
                    <td>Authorised By</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="authorisedby" id="wgtmsr">
                        <option value="<%=res.getString(13)%>"><%=res.getString(13)%></option>
                        <option value="Soma Ghosh">Soma Ghosh</option>
                        <option value="KV Suresh">KV Suresh</option>
                        <option value="Raghavendra Deolankar">Raghavendra Deolankar</option>
                        <option value="Shriram Aparnnaa">Shriram Aparnnaa</option>
                    </select>
                    </td>
                
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td>Validity - From date</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="date" required="" name="fromdate" value='<%=res.getString(14)%>'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Validity - To Date</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="date" required="" name="todate" value='<%=res.getString(15)%>'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                
                
                <!–– Code for QMS start   ––>
                
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="chk">QMS</label></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="chk" id="chk" value="check" onclick="showHide()"/>
                        
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td><label class="hidden">Document Level(F31151)</label></td>
                    <td>
                        
                        <select name="documentlevel" class="hidden" id="wgtmsr">
                        <option value="<%=res.getString(16)%>"><%=res.getString(16)%></option>
                        <option value="0: QMM">0: QMM</option>
                        <option value="1: Business-Process">1: Business-Process</option>
                        <option value="2: Process & Descriptions">2: Process & Descriptions</option>
                        <option value="3: Work Instructions">Work Instructions</option>
                        <option value="4: Checklist & Form">Checklist & Form</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td><label class="hidden">Document 00 General</label></td>
                    <td>
                        
                        <select name="documentgeneral" class="hidden" id="wgtmsr">
                        <option value="<%=res.getString(17)%>"><%=res.getString(17)%></option>
                        <option value="00 General">00 General</option>
                        <option value="01 SDP Strategy Development Process">01 SDP Strategy Development Process</option>
                        <option value="02 Sales & Application Process">02 Sales & Application Process</option>
                        <option value="03 PDP Product Development Process">03 PDP Product Development Process</option>
                        <option value="04 PP Purchasing process">04 PP Purchasing process</option>
                        <option value="05 MP Maintenance Process">05 MP Maintenance Process</option>
                        <option value="06 Manufacturing & Delivery Process">06 Manufacturing & Delivery Process</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td><label class="hidden">Serial Number</label></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="serialnumber" class="hidden" value='<%=res.getString(18)%>'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td><label class="hidden">Revision No.</label></td>
                    <td >
                        
                        <select name="revisionnumber" class="hidden" id="wgtmsr">
                        <option value=""><%=res.getString(19)%></option>
                        <option value="00">00</option>
                        <option value="01">01</option>
                        <option value="02">02</option>
                        <option value="03">03</option>
                        <option value="04">04</option>
                        <option value="05">05</option>
                        <option value="06">06</option>
                        <option value="07">07</option>
                        <option value="08">08</option>
                        <option value="09">09</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        <option value="13">13</option>
                        <option value="14">14</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                
                
                <tr>
                    <td><label class="hidden">Issuer</label></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="issuer" class="hidden" value='<%=res.getString(20)%>'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td><label class="hidden">Status</label></td>
                    <td>
                        
                        <select name="status" class="hidden" id="wgtmsr">
                        <option value=""><%=res.getString(21)%></option>
                        <option value="Public">Reserved</option>
                        <option value="Team">Implemented</option>
                        
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
  
                
                <!–– Code for QMS end   ––>
                
                
                
                
                <tr>
                    <td>Select File</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="file" name="fileName" multiple="multiple" value='<%=res.getString("filename")%>'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                <%
                    
                   
                    }


                %>    
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
                
                   
        </form>
        <br>
        <center><a href="home.jsp">Home</a></center>
    </div>
    </div>  
    </div>
    </div>
                <%
            String z_id = request.getParameter("zid");
            String first_Name = request.getParameter("firstname");
            String last_Name = request.getParameter("lastname");
            String mail_i_d = request.getParameter("mailid");
            String d_iv = request.getParameter("division");
            String de_pt = request.getParameter("department");
            String cost_centercode = request.getParameter("costcentercode");
            String doc_num = request.getParameter("documentnumber");                 //textbox value of documentnumber field
            String doc_Name = request.getParameter("documentname");
            String doc_Type = request.getParameter("Document_Type");                 //textbox value of Document_Type field
            String doc_Category = request.getParameter("Document_Category");   
            String doc_classification = request.getParameter("Document_Classification");
            String authorised_by = request.getParameter("authorisedby");
            String from_date = request.getParameter("fromdate");
            String to_date = request.getParameter("todate");
            
            String document_level = request.getParameter("documentlevel");
            String document_general = request.getParameter("documentgeneral");
            String serial_number = request.getParameter("serialnumber");
            String revision_number = request.getParameter("revisionnumber");
            String iss_uer = request.getParameter("issuer");
            String sta_tus = request.getParameter("status");
            String file_Name = "";
            String folder_Name = "allfiles";
            String pa_th = folder_Name + File.separator + file_Name;
            Timestamp add_ed_date = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
            
            if(z_id != null && first_Name != null && last_Name != null && mail_i_d != null && d_iv != null && de_pt != null && cost_centercode != null && doc_num != null && doc_Name != null && doc_Type != null && doc_Category != null && doc_classification != null && authorised_by != null && from_date != null && to_date != null && document_level != null && document_general != null && serial_number != null && revision_number != null && iss_uer != null && sta_tus != null && file_Name != null && folder_Name != null && pa_th != null && add_ed_date != null){
                String query = "update dmsfiles set zid=?,firstname=?,lastname=?,mailid=?,division=?,department=?,costcentercode=?,document_number=?,document_name=?,document_type=?,document_category=?,document_classification=?,authorised_by=?,fromdate=?,todate=?,document_level=?,document_general=?,serial_number=?,revision_number=?,issuer=?,status=?,filename=?,path=?,added_date=? where zid='"+z_id+"'";
                stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                
                stmt.setString(1,z_id);
                stmt.setString(2,first_Name);
                stmt.setString(3,last_Name);
                stmt.setString(4,mail_i_d);
                stmt.setString(5,d_iv);
                stmt.setString(6,de_pt);
                stmt.setString(7,cost_centercode);
                stmt.setString(8,doc_num);
                stmt.setString(9,doc_Name);
                stmt.setString(10,doc_Type);
                stmt.setString(11,doc_Category);
                stmt.setString(12,doc_classification);
                stmt.setString(13,authorised_by);
                stmt.setString(14,from_date);
                stmt.setString(15,to_date);
                stmt.setString(16,document_level);
                stmt.setString(17,document_general);
                stmt.setString(18,serial_number);
                stmt.setString(19,revision_number);
                stmt.setString(20,iss_uer);
                stmt.setString(21,sta_tus);
                stmt.setString(22,file_Name);
                
                stmt.setString(23,pa_th);
                stmt.setTimestamp(24, null);
                stmt.executeUpdate();
                response.sendRedirect("filelist.jsp");
                
                
                
                
                
            }
    
    

%>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this below image you can see that all textfields, dropdowns that I have fetched from database but I didn't get filename
[image]

Comment: I have one index.jsp page, in this user will fill details like firstname, lastname, dropdown list are also there, select file(s) that user want to upload and then submit the form. Then In filelist.jsp page, user will see all files uploaded and click on "edit" option to to changes as per need. So when user will click on "edit" then edit.jsp will open with previous stored values(by fetching from database). So in this, previous stored filename should be shown on <input type="file" name="fileName" multiple="multiple" value='<%=res.getString("filename")%>'/>

Comment: I am trying to fetch not only fields and dropdowns from database but also I want previous stored filename on input jsp page.

Comment: please help me in this

Comment: We need to see more code, especially the select statement etc.

Comment: Can you give more detail, Why you have setting file value in file input field. For edit you need to select other file using file browser and store this file name in any hidden field . You can show existing image/file to view or download if file exists  and also show file browser to change existing file.

Comment: please help....

Comment: As your datatype to retrieve your file is not `blob` its `string` you cannot display that value in `<input ..type="file">` instead you can show it like this  `<span> <%=res.getString("filename")%>  </span>` below your `file` input type.